# FiddlerScript class reference?

Tags: fiddler, manual, fiddler-dev

I am looking for a language or class reference for FiddlerScript.

The Fiddler ScriptEditor has a class explorer. But this only contains a very limited amount of documentation.

For example, what methods are available for the `Hashtable` or `JSON.JSONParseResult` classes? What can I do to get the current system time?

Then language looks a lot like CSharp but is just different enough that using CSharp documentation is frustrating.

A normal class reference of language manual is necessary, and also sufficient to answer all my other questions.

Comment: From the website: _FiddlerScript is based on JScript.net_. The classes itself are AFAIK just standard .Net.

Comment: Is there a reference for JScript.NET that is still alive? A lot of Microsoft references have been redirected to JavaScript. Being a lot like other .NET languages is nice, but that still doesn't give me the documentation to, say, create a literal ArrayList.

Comment: JScript.NET is very similar to JavaScript and Java. Therefore it is also similar to C# therefore code will work just just minor modifications. There are also translators available. The closest I found is C#->TypeScript: https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/ (TypeScript also very close to JScript.Net)

Answer (score 1):

FiddlerScript uses JScript.NET language, which is not so supported and popular these days. There is an [online tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa289164(v=vs.100)), and Eric Lawrence also recommends Justin Rogers's [Microsoft JScript.NET Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672321483) book as an advanced JScript.NET reference.

Otherwise [Understanding FiddlerScript](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-fiddlerscript) blogpost by Eric Lawrence is a good entry-level tutorial specifically for FiddlerScript, more info is also available in the [Debugging with Fiddler](https://fiddlerbook.com/book/) book. Using the Fiddler ScriptEditor (installed with Fiddler) also eases FiddlerScript development.

JScript.NET-based extensibility is preserved and enabled by default for more of a compatibility reasons, but for new projects you can use C# as an extensibility language by choosing C# in `Tools -> Options -> Scripting -> Language` in Fiddler options.